# Rendering to a cube texture and then sampling it?

Tags: vulkan

I want to render a scene to the six faces of a cube texture (ie the same scene from six different perpendicular cameras) and then I want to sample from the cube texture from a fragment shader while rendering to the final framebuffer to be presented.

Is the best way to organize that to have a render pass with 7 subpasses? 1 subpass for each face of the cube texture and then the final subpass to sample the cube texture?

Or will that not work?

If it will work, roughly how do I describe the cube texture in the render pass attachments?

If it won't work, what's the best way to organize it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use two render passes. You would need to read from the cubemap as a cubemap rather than as an input attachment, so you need to break your render pass up to do that.

The cubemap rendering pass should just use a layered attachment and layered rendering functionality to send each primitive to the appropriate layer. The final pass just works as normal.

Comment: Thanks, but I can't seem to find references to layered attachment or layered rendering in the vulkan spec?  Do you mean the "multiview" stuff around "VkRenderPassMultiviewCreateInfo"?

Comment: No, I mean [layered rendering](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Layered_Rendering). You know, rendering to an image view that has layers by using the GS (or VS) to specify which layer in the image a primitive gets rendered to? Vulkan can do that too. That's why `VkFramebufferCreateInfo` has a `layers` field.

Comment: Hmmm, I might try that as a plan B.  I'm going to try two render passes, the first just having six subpasses that vary by camera position - and drawing the complete scene in each subpass.  I figure because of the usual culling that performance won't be too terrible.  It's not clear to me in the layered rendering approach what do you do with a triangle that overlaps two (or more) of the cube faces (layers)?

Comment: Regarding a triangle that overlaps multiple faces/layers: When using layered rendering, the geometry has to be amplified at some point during the pipeline as well --- once for each face/target layer. Such a geometry amplification can be done by the means of instancing or by emitting each input triangle in a geometry shader six times, sending each one to a different layer. The potential advantage of such an approach is reduced driver overhead (fewer draw calls) and the possibility for further performance optimization (manual culling). You *can* gain some performance from such an approach.